# Cakephp 4 - Merge two ResultSet

Tags: cakephp, collections, query-builder, cakephp-4.x

I got two ResultSet as the result of a query->find().

Now I would like to merge both in a specific order, e.g. iterate through ResultSet1 and after every 10th item I would like to merge in one of the items from ResultSet2.

I found the appendItem function, however it doesn't seem to sort my item at the right place.

Any suggestions?

Reason for staying with the ResultSet in the Controller: I would like to deliver the result to a template/view, as well as serialize it and deliver as JSON.

Thanks
Christian

Comment: Sounds to me like the sort of thing that calls for a custom JSON output template instead of using the default serialization.

Comment: This is really what I would like to avoid, since it would duplicate logic once in the HTML template and same logic in the JSON template…

Comment: An example of your datasets, and what the result should look like could be helpful, as there's quite a few ways to skin a Roti Island Snake-Necked Turtle.

Comment: I skinned it now by transforming both of my ResultSets ->toArray and then did the necessary merging with the arrays. I thought it's not as elegant as working with the collections but it does the job too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly your data looks like, but for the sake of completeness, here's some funny collection foo:

```php
$itemsA = collection([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]);
$itemsB = collection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']);
```

Using custom unfolding to yield elements after the chunks:

```php
$collection = $itemsA
    ->chunk(2)
    ->unfold(function (array $chunks, int $key) use ($itemsB) {
        // yield every itemA element in the chunk
        yield from $chunks;

        // only yield itemB element in case there's 2 preceding itemA elements
        if (count($chunks) === 2) {
            static $index = 0;

            // yield itemB element in case one exists at the (next) index
            $itemB = $itemsB->take(1, $index ++)->first();
            if ($itemB) {
                yield $itemB;
            }
        }
    });
```

Using mapping to append elements to the chunks:

```php
$collection = $itemsA
    ->chunk(2)
    ->map(function (array $chunk) use ($itemsB) {
        // only add itemB element in case there's 2 preceding itemA elements
        if (count($chunk) === 2) {
            static $index = 0;

            // add itemB element in case one exists at the (next) index
            $itemB = $itemsB->take(1, $index ++)->first();
            if ($itemB) {
                $chunk[] = $itemB;
            }
        }

        return $chunk;
    })
    ->unfold();
```

With both examples, `$collection->toArray()` would return:

```php
[
  (int) 0 => (int) 1,
  (int) 1 => (int) 2,
  (int) 2 => 'a',
  (int) 3 => (int) 3,
  (int) 4 => (int) 4,
  (int) 5 => 'b',
  (int) 6 => (int) 5,
  (int) 7 => (int) 6,
  (int) 8 => 'c',
  (int) 9 => (int) 7,
  (int) 10 => (int) 8,
  (int) 11 => 'd',
  (int) 12 => (int) 9,
  (int) 13 => (int) 10,
  (int) 14 => 'e',
  (int) 15 => (int) 11
]
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::map()](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::map)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::chunk()](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::chunk)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Collection::unfold()](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::unfold)**